# Plymouth to LightDM smooth transition

Tags: lightdm, plymouth

I have set the grub background, plymouth splash background and desktop wallpaper all to the same image just to give a more uniform boot process.

The only issue I have now is the transition from plymouth to LightDM is not smooth. What I mean is, the screen goes black for around 2 seconds while plymouth hands over to LightDM.

I have searched around and the best I can find is this from 'aur.archlinux.org' :

1. The DM and plymouthd have to be started on the same tty otherwise there will not be smooth transition.
2. 'X-background none" should also help with smooth transition.

Could do with some help finding out what 'x-background' is and how to configure plymouth and/or LightDM tty.

Thanks.